# Property does not exist on type (inside of editor)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following `TypeScript` interface and method:

```
namespace a {

  export interface componentType<T extends component> {
    new(element?: HTMLElement): T
    runStaticTick(comp: componentType<T>, tick?: number): void
  }

  export abstract class component {

    public static components: component[] = []

    public findComponent<T extends component>(comp: componentType<T>, callback?: (comp: T) => void) {
      let c = component.components.find(c => c instanceof comp) as T
      c instanceof component && typeof callback == 'function' && callback(c)
      return c
    }

  }

  export abstract class element extends component { }
}
```

This is the **.d.ts**

```
declare namespace a {
  interface componentType<T extends component> {
    new(element?: HTMLElement): T;
  }
  abstract class component {
    findComponent<T extends component>(comp: componentType<T>, callback?: (comp: T) => void): T;
  }
  abstract class element extends component { }
}
```

Then, to test if the method works, I have this `JavaScript`:

```
/// <reference path="../src/test.d.ts"/>

class checklist extends a.element {
  sayHi() { console.log('Hi') }
}

class myclass extends a.component {
  created() {
    this.findComponent(checklist, item => {
      item.sayHi()
    })
  }
}
```

The code works in the browser, but in the editor, it says that `item` is of type `component` when it should be of type `checklist`. Is there a way to fix this or is this an issue with typescript?

For the full project: https://github.com/TheColorRed/horsepower

### Edit

I figured out what is causing the issue:

```
export interface componentType<T extends component> {
  new(element?: HTMLElement): T
  runStaticTick(comp: componentType<T>, tick?: number): void
}
```

If I comment out `runStaticTick` it fixes the intellisense problem. But then I have errors saying that it doesn't exist:

> error TS2339: Property 'runStaticTick' does not exist on type 'componentType'

Comment: I tried and it works in VS Code. Could you post a complete example

Comment: That is what I am using and it is not working....

Comment: Could it be that I am using a `tsconfig.json` file in `src` and a `jsconfig.json` in my `public/app` folder?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have created a new project, and copied the above code to the project and it works there. Why doesn't it work in my current project? I have tried both `TS 2.7` and `TS 2.8` neither work. What else could be causing the issue?

Comment: What editor are you using?  Might be good to tag the question with the editor in question.

Comment: @cale_b I am using vscode (tag added)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Try closing your editor and re-opening it. I get that sometimes when I change d.ts files, they built-in TS doesn't pick it up until I re-open VSCode

Comment: I have, I also installed the new update `1.20.1` about 20 min ago

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Have you tried `(item) => ...`? Maybe it doesn't recognize the arrow function properly for some reason? Just a shot in the dark

Comment: @mhodges same thing `function(item) ...`, `(item) => ...` both produce the same error

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn What about `(item:checklist) => ...`?

Comment: Can't do that with JavaScript, (which is where the error is). It works fine if I use TypeScript for the tests, just not the javascript.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Oh, the bottom portion is a `.js` file?

Comment: Yeah, that is a `.js` file

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Is the `checklist` being passed into the `findComponent` function an instance of the class? Maybe you have to say `findComponent(new checklist(), ...)`?

Comment: @mhodges it shouldn't need one. it works as a non-instance in TypeScript, and in my simplified version (above). Just not in the complete project. **Side note:** You can just run `Restart TS Server` from the command palet to reload the `.d.ts` and project instead of restarting the editor.

Comment: Looks like it is the way the `.d.ts` file is built. If I replace it with the simplified one above, then it seems to work.

Comment: I have figured out the problem see above edit. I just don't know why it is happening. Is this causing an endless reference?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of the property within the method `runStaticTick`.

Instead using using

```
comp: componentType<T>
```

I should be using

```
comp: componentType<component>
```

For some reason, `T` was causing issues of which I do not know. If someone knows what that issue is, please let me know.